# How to store token when using OAuth2 API

Tags: angularjs, node.js, api, rest, oauth

I am building an Angular front-end application which consumes data from the from the [Strava API](https://strava.github.io/api/v3/oauth/). I have built a back end service in Node and ExpressJS which stores my client ID and client secret, and redirects the user to Strava's authentication page so they can give permission for my app to request their data.

After authentication, Strava redirects the user back to my app with their access token as a query string parameter. The access token needs to be submitted to the API with every subsequent request.

I am wondering about the pros and cons of how to make requests to the API. As I understand it, I have the following options:

1. Store the access token client side in a cookie, and submit requests directly to the Strava API from the front end. This would need to be done using JSONP because of the same origin policy. (The Strava API supports JSONP).
2. Store the access token server side in a session variable in my node application, and make all requests via the node server. I would build my own API to allow the front end to communicate with the node application.

What are the pros and cons of each approach?

Answer (score 0):

For anything non trivial the server side approach is the way to go. Building your own REST API gives you much more flexibility and it helps you separate your concerns - your Angular app is probably not the best place for heavy REST API logic.

Each REST API provider have a rate/quota limit of their API. So making each request in real time through your Angular app to the Strava API might not be an option. You may need to create some sort of background worker service that caches the needed data from the Strava database on certain interval of time. Then you show that cached data to your users, each time they make request to your web site.